# Can't solve "Cannot POST /contact.php" ERROR

Tags: php, html

I keep getting an ERROR "Cannot POST /contact.php". please help!! Below is my code

This is index.html

```
<form action="/contact.php" method="post">
        <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
          <div class="w3-half">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="sender">
          </div>
          <div class="w3-half">
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="senderEmail">
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" required name="message">
        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-right w3-section" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> SEND MESSAGE
        </button>
      </form>
```

This is contact.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $recipient="my@email.addres";
    $subject="Email from Matabots Website";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");
}

?>
```

I'm using the Brackets Editor and the Live Preview Option to test my website before I post it.

I want it so that when a user submits the form on index.html, the user's Name, email, and message are emailed to my personal email. Please Help. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Try using replace form tag like this `<form action="contact.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

If the location of index.html and contact.php are same in the folder then you should remove the leading slash from action.

If that doesn't work add full url in action that domain.com/contact.php

Answer (score 0):

The `/` as first char in a path is used for a absolute path (a path that starts from the root system directory).

So, if `contact.php` is in the same directory where is located the form page try this:

```
action="contact.php"
```

otherwise specify the relative path like this:

```
action="subDir/subDir2/contact.php"
// or
action="../otherDir/contact.php"
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for some reason. I think I should mention that I'm using the Live Preview option in Brackets to see my website before I post it.